# Strange BUG, MPMovieControlStyleNone VS SpriteKit

Tags: video, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller, sprite-kit, mpmoviewcontroller

Very strange bug!

Ok so I am creating a game using Sprite Kit.

On launch a video is played (MPMoviePlayerController)

Once the video has stopped playing I am using the following code to Dismiss it...

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

    _moviePlayer = [notification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:_moviePlayer];

    if ([_moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {

         _moviePlayer.fullscreen = NO;
        [_moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];


    }
}
```

Once the video has been removed it reveals the game.

However as soon as the the game appears, the Background Image appears blurred or to have low contrast, but then fades in to look normal again over around 2-3 seconds.

I have found the cause of the problem....

It seems when i set

```
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

the bug happens. But when I set

```
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

It is fine!!

I don't want to see or have any controls though!..

Has anyone came across this before/ know how I could resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Dan.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `MPMoviePlayerController` you could use the `AVPlayer`:

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFileName" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
SKVideoNode *introVideo = [[SKVideoNode alloc] initWithAVPlayer: player];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[player currentItem]];
```

And:

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
     // Remove AVPlayer, remove Observer...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't quite work exactly how I wanted but It has lead me to a fix by using SKVideoNode!